# Read out specific letters from the right via MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a varchar field that contains a description with variable lenght. I want to read out the 3. and the 4. letter from the right.

For example if the table contained:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|16_1215|
|15_1122|
|20170812|
|20170407|
|16_0811|
|20180929|
```

I want a query that will return:

```
|result|
+------+
|12|
|11|
|08|
|04|
|08|
|09|
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with right and left

```
SELECT left(right(col1,4),2) FROM tbl
```